# Send bulk emails with multiple attachments to multiple recipients

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I found this code to send bulk emails to multiple recipients by Outlook with Excel VBA.

What should I add to it to send two attachments not one?

```vb
Sub Send_Multiple_Email()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    Dim oa As Object
    Dim msg As Object
    
    Set oa = CreateObject("outlook.Application")
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim last_row As Integer
    
    last_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))
    
    For i = 2 To last_row
        Set msg = oa.createitem(0)
    
        msg.to = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
        msg.Subject = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
        msg.body = sh.Range("c" & i).Value
    
        If sh.Range("D" & i).Value <> "" Then
            msg.attachments.Add sh.Range("D" & i).Value
        End If
    
        msg.display
     
     Next i
      
     MsgBox "mails sent"
     
End Sub
```

Comment: `what should I add to it to send 2 attachments not just one?` **1.** Which part of the code do you think is adding attachments? **2.** What is the criteria for the 2nd attachment? **3.** What do you think should be changed?

Comment: when i dublicated the part of the code included the attachments it didn't work it said that next without for i forgot to put end if so i came here to ask

Answer (score 0):

Add information to `E2` till the end row and add there what you want to attach like , what is done with `D`.

And you can add more columns f G H I J K .. with more attachments

If the cell is empty, no attachment is added

```
If sh.Range("D" & i).Value <> "" Then
    msg.attachments.Add sh.Range("D" & i).Value
End If

If sh.Range("E" & i).Value <> "" Then
    msg.attachments.Add sh.Range("E" & i).Value
End If

msg.display
```

Comment: it worked thanks, but why the emails i sent went to spam or junk however when I repeated to send same email from outlook app on android to the same recipient it was sent to the inbox, what is the problem?